# Pre Dexing gwt-user.jar causes a OutOfMemoryError from the Garbage Collector

Tags: java, gwt, compiler-construction, intellij-13, garbage

I've been trying to get gwt set up with an Android project and after adding the sdk to my build path, the compilation hangs on this problem.

I am using IntelliJ Ultimate 13.1 and the android app is the skeleton that comes with it.

here is the full traceback:

```
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] Unable to execute DX
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at com.android.dx.util.Bits.makeBitSet(Bits.java:38)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at com.android.dx.util.BitIntSet.<init>(BitIntSet.java:35)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at com.android.dx.ssa.SetFactory.makeDomFrontSet(SetFactory.java:66)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at com.android.dx.ssa.DomFront.run(DomFront.java:103)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaConverter.placePhiFunctions(SsaConverter.java:297)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaConverter.convertToSsaMethod(SsaConverter.java:51)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:98)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:72)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:299)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:139)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:94)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:682)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.runDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:161)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gwt-user.jar] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.main(AndroidDxRunner.java:294)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclosure: I've never done any serious Android dev, and I don't actually know what "pre dex" really means.*

There's absolutely no reason to package gwt-user into an Android app.

Either you package JS that's been produced by GWT, and you only need GWT at compile-time; or you want to use RequestFactory and you should use `requestfactory-client.jar` instead. There might be other situations where you want to use other GWT classes that are not in `requestfactory-client` (e.g. `RegExp` or `SafeHtml`), in which case you'd have to either extract them into your own JAR, or maybe just use `gwt-servlet`.

Comment: That seems reasonable, I guess I was using GWT and wasn't really sure why, will look at pulling it out of my project, thanks!